# Check nginx cache expiration time

Tags: caching, nginx

I want to ask again before cache file expires. So, I want to know current expiration time of each cache files.

How does nginx supervise the cache structure?

I think... to be managed by db about cache file key.

I'd really appreciate if anyone could give me a useful information.

Comment: The ngx_http_headers_module module allows adding the “Expires” and “Cache-Control” header fields, and arbitrary fields, to a response header.http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html

Comment: I had already set uwsgi_cache_valid 200 720m; . I want to know how much expire time left.